# Function score with filters elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to have a function, that takes all the results and only orders them if they match the filters.
I've tried with these queries but no result. Can someone help with this?

Tryout 1:

```
{
           "query": {
                "function_score": {
                    "query": {
                        "filtered": {
                            "query": {
                                "match_all": {} 
                            },                        
                            "filter": {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must": [
                                        {
                                            "term": {
                                                "category_boats": "motor_boat"
                                            }
                                        }                                           
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "functions": [

                    ],
                    "score_mode": "first"
                }
            }
        }
```

Tryout 2:

```
{
           "query": {
                "function_score": {
                    "query": { 
                        "match_all": {}
                    },
                    "functions": [ 
                        {
                            "filter": { 
                                "term": { 
                                    "boat_type": "offshore_yacht" 
                                }
                            }, 
                            "weight": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "filter": { 
                                "term": { 
                                    "year_built": "2016" 
                                }
                            }, 
                            "weight": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "filter": { 
                                "term": { 
                                    "manufacturer": "MasterCraft" 
                                }
                            }, 
                            "weight": 2 
                        }
                    ],
                    "score_mode": "first"
                }
            }
        }
```

On the last code I get an error: No function with the name [weight] is registered.]
So is weight for filter supported or not? Some help?

Comment: which version of elasticsearch ?

Comment: Version: "number" : "1.3.2". But if this is a problem I can update the ElasticSearch server

Comment: curious doesn't the below approach work?

Comment: I works the solutions bellow. Thanks Keety

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Support for [weight](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-score-weight) was added in elasticsearch 1.4 prior to that it was referred to as `boost_factor`

Example:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "boat_type": "offshore_yacht"
            }
          },
          "boost_factor": 1
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "year_built": "2016"
            }
          },
          "boost_factor": 1
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "manufacturer": "MasterCraft"
            }
          },
          "boost_factor": 2
        }
      ],
      "score_mode": "first"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Keety. It works. I didn't know that "weight" is only for the Elastic after 1.4.
I was always confused in the tutorials and examples why there is sometimes "weight" and sometimes "boost_factor"

Comment: I have difficulty implementing this in Elastic "2.2.0". They changed something on how the filtering is done.
It's not simply replacing "boost_factor" with "weight".
Can someone help?

Comment: just tried the above query in answer and works fine for me in elasticsearch 2.2.0 . Could you file another question with the actual query that you are executing and the problem you are facing in 2.2.0

Comment: This query above lists the results - true, but they are not sorted by the boost_factor or weight like they are in Elasticsearch 1.3.2.
It shown the results, from "match_all": {}, but not sorted anything we want by the filters like version 1.3.2. It must be some other way...